# Conservation of Angular Momentum in Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum

In an old set of course notes on electrodynamics, the reader is asked to derive following equation:
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{l}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial\mathbf{l}_m}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\left(\mathcal{T}\times\mathbf{r}\right)=0 \, ,
$$
where $\mathbf{l}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{g}$, $\mathbf{g}=\varepsilon\mu\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{H}$, $\mathcal{T}$ is the Maxwell stress tensor $$(\mathcal{T})_{ij}=T_{ij}=H_iB_j+E_iD_j-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{H}+\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{E}\right)\delta_{ij}$$ and $\mathbf{l}_m$ is described as being the "density of the mechanical angular momentum".

Has anyone ever seen this equation before in the literature on electrodynamics?

Comment: See (1.17) [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bf92/341d181b871ff30d9cc36d0491607bd10012.pdf?_ga=2.159233849.2070487483.1587168424-916525785.1587168424).

Comment: That was fast! Thanks!